# How to create 2 vertical left right pane with header and footer pane layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Just like this

<--Header-->

Left  |  Right

<--Footer-->

Where I will put a search `textBox` on header pane and then a `listView` on left pane and the right pane will have text field to display detail about selected item in `listView`. The footer will have some `Buttons` on it.

Comment: Uh, hm, why not show some effort yourself first? Where is your xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not usually a fan of "ask and get" method. You must show what you have tried so far and explain what is not working on your code. But since you haven't given more feedback about your issue, here it goes.  You can have a simple layout like that just using `LinearLayouts` and `RelativeLayouts` as parent `Views`. Then, insert the specific `Views` you are referring  (`TextView`, `ListView`) inside those parent views. Like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Description" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />
    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is just a scratch. But from here, you can costumize it as you like.

Comment: Hi, it's my first time android development so please bear with me. I  tried your layout code and it gaves 2 errors. First on <LinearLayout attribute is missing the android namespace prefix so i tried put xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" below it and it resolved the error. Second error is at <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/contentLayout" it says The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. I can't see what is causing this error...

Comment: @Eddi I am sorry, I edited my code and it's all working now. Just copy it and try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.layouttest.MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:text="I am Header" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="I am Footer" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="2px"
        android:padding="5dp" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Details of List View" />
</LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will help you :)

Comment: Working nicely. Thanks!
Btw how could i change the width size of the listview to smaller like 25%? I tried android:layout_weight="1" for listview and "4" for textview but it has no effect.

Comment: I figured it. Have to increase android:weightSum at the LinearLayout.

Comment: If you remove the android:weightSum from the LinearLayout then it will adjust automatically according to their child weights.

Answer (score 0):

[This Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-header-and-footer-layout-example.html)
 May help you to handle Header and Footer in RelativeLayout.

Comment: Hi, this is very close to what i need. How could i make the Content layout to have a left and right pane inside so i could put a listview on left pane and the item detail on right pane?

Comment: "joao2fast4u" already solve your problem. I think I don't have to explain further. :)

Comment: If you have time please explain how to do it too. I would like to learn and so i will have option to use joao's method or this one. Thanks.